# Define command with optional characters

Tags: macros

I have the following command definition (in the MWE)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\hE_#1^#2#3{\hat {\textrm{E}}_{#1}^{#2}\,[#3]}

\begin{document}
\[
  \hE_{1}^{2}{3},\qquad
  % \hE^{2}{3},\qquad
  % \hE_{1}{3},\qquad.
  % \hE^{2}_{1}{3},\qquad
  % \hE{3}
\]
\end{document}
```

Which outputs a particular expression with superscripts and subscripts. I want to define other usages of this command that allow for the commented variants. I thought I could do this

```
\def\hE^#1_#2#3{\hE_{#2}^{#1}{#3}}
\def\hE^#1#2{\hE_{}^{#1}{#2}}
\def\hE_#1#2{\hE_{#1}^{}{#2}}
```

But that gave me a `TeX capacity exceeded` error. Is there a way to do this? I prefer to use internal tex definitions rather than external packages if possible.

Comment: Probably a better idea to use `xparse` than to try to do this via `\def`

Comment: Honestly? Just write `\newcommand*{\hE}{\hat{\mathrm{E}}}` and fill the rest manually. _Much_ more readable code than what you are trying to define (IMO). But if you _really_ want _that_ you might be interested in the `e` argument of `xparse`.

Comment: I would like to not have to repeat `\,[...]` for every usage of this command. Especially since I might decide to change the spacing later or change the delimiter. IMO, my usage is more readable from the point of view of content-focused writing.

Comment: @daleif, I am not too familiar with `xparse`. While I prefer to use the standard TeX engine, I am not opposed to packages if they make life much simpler. I will `xparse` manual and see what I can do.

Comment: Your def will only be able to take stuff in a certain order. But the `e` type in `xparse` can handle `^_` options in any order. `xparse` will be worth your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `xparse`. The `e` argument type takes a list of tokens and in the body `#1` refers to the item after the first token, `#2` to the item after the second token and so on. You can test whether they are present with `\IfValueT`.

I'd not add the `\,` thin space. If you prefer, add it in the following code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hE}{e{^_}m}{%
  \mathop{}\!\hat{\mathrm{E}}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}%
  [#3]%
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \hE_{1}^{2}{3},\quad
  \hE^{2}{3},\quad
  \hE_{1}{3},\quad
  \hE^{2}_{1}{3},\quad
  \hE{3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output with `\,` for comparison:

[image]

I believe it's evident that the thin space is out of place, but you're the final judge.

On the other hand, I'd simply do

```
\newcommand{\hE}{\mathop{}\!\hat{\mathrm{E}}}
```

and type in the brackets.

```
\hE_{1}^{2}[3],\quad
\hE^{2}[3],\quad
\hE_{1}[3],\quad
\hE^{2}_{1}[3],\quad
\hE[3]
```

As you see, there is no gain with the proposed syntax (other than the possibility to insert the thin space).

More importantly, `\textrm{E}` is not the right tool; `\mathrm{E}` is.

Why `\mathop{}\!`? Because this way `\hE` is treated as a math operator like `\sin` or `\log`. I opted to not doing `\operatorname{\hat{E}}`, because in this way the superscript would be too high.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. I want to combine this syntax with `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` from `mathtools` to allow subscripts and superscript on the operator and also to have the possibility to change the delimiters, which is why I asked this question.